# Must we avoid long answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

When we flag a question as being *too broad*, we can read:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   **too long** for this format.

Can we conclude from this statement that  giving a long answer is a bad thing to do? If yes, why?

Comment: I would love to flag some answers with "too bored".. Pardon the pun.

Comment: @Ulkoma you have nothing else to do tonight? :)

Comment: I am doing a night shift tonight :)

Comment: For context, the stereotypical example of a "too long" answer as used above is a textbook. So, a "too broad" question might be "what happened in the British Empire in the 18th century" (sorry, that was easier than thinking of an InfoSec-specific example). Anything of a length that our system will actually accept should be fine, as long as it otherwise meets our quality standards.

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification @Pops

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a purely technical point-of-view, too long answers are answers containing more than 30,000 characters (meaning around 5000 English words!). Yes they are bad things and are actually truncated according to [this Meta SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25066/please-notify-me-of-the-30-000-character-limit).

But this remains an exceptional situation.

When one flags a question as *too broad*, the issue is not really that the answer would be long, there are good long answers (the canonical ones being the best examples), but the issue would be that **the answer will also be too broad**.

The "*format*" mentioned in your quoted text implies a precise question being associated to precise answers. The goal of this is that SE answers can be used as direct reference by other people: Your question has already been asked? SE serves you directly the most sensible answers. It becomes a real time-saver.

When the question is too broad, whether because it not precise enough or actually include several "sub-questions", then the answer will have to cover all possibles situations or answer every sub-questions. Such answers becomes less usable for the purpose of this site: Here are a bunch of information around your subject, maybe your answer is in-there, maybe not, we let you sort this out...

[An interesting reading on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59235/long-answers-on-stackoverflow) can be found on Meta SE, I would tend to summarize all-this by saying that a SE answer should remained focused and avoid digressions and irrelevant informations, all this being impossible when trying to answer an already "*too broad*" question.